# trying to use hover to show a clickable image when the mouse enters

Tags: css, html, hover

Reading a lot of possible answers, but maybe I'm just not that smart. I would like to do this using CSS and html5 rather than JavaScript if possible, if not then I guess I'll need to go that route.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
an image of a machine is displayed on the page inside a div.
On hover, I want a clickable highlighted version of the image displayed.

I would also like other informational text and images to become visible using a fadein tag.
When the mouse exits the image, I want the highlighted version and additional images and text to be invisible again.
There are 10 pieces of equipment I need to do this with. All on the same page.

I am thinking that each piece needs to be in its own div inside the overall div.

```
<!-- Animation Begins --> 
<div class="animated_lines" style="z-index: 910; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 150px; opacity: 0.5;"> 

<!-- Vertical Blend Button Start -->    
<div class="productionlines" style="z-index: 920; margin-left: -350px; margin-top: -280px; opacity: 1;"> 
  <img src="images/productionlines/baked/verticalblender.png" /> 
</div> 
<!-- Vertical Blend Button End -->


.productionline { 
  background-image: url(images/productionlines/baked/verticalblender.png); 
} 
.productionline:hover { 
  background-image: url(images/productionlines/baked/verticalblender-highlighted.png); 
}
```

-Thanks

Comment: Please post any code you've already started, and preferably, a JSFiddle or CodePen demo of that code for testing.

Comment: <!-- Animation Begins  -->
    <div class="animated_lines" style="z-index: 910; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 150px; opacity: 0.5;">

     
    <!-- Vertical Blend Button Start -->    
      <div class="productionlines" style="z-index: 920; margin-left: -350px; margin-top: -280px; opacity: 1;">
      <img src="images/productionlines/baked/verticalblender.png" />
      </div>
    <!-- Vertical Blend Button End -->

Comment: CSS looks like this- Super simple, but that may be the problem:.productionline {
    background-image: url(images/productionlines/baked/verticalblender.png);

}


.productionline:hover {
    background-image: url(images/productionlines/baked/verticalblender-highlighted.png);
}

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly you need to change the image using css on hover.

The easiest way is to put in html both images and to work with display:none and display:block;

```
 .image {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
}
.image .hover {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.image:hover .hover {
    display:block;
}
.image:hover .original {
    display:none;
}

    <div class="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="original" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Cute-Ball-Search-icon.png" width="112" height="112" alt="" />
        <img class="hover" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Perspective-Button-Search-icon.png" width="112" height="112" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img class="original" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Cute-Ball-Search-icon.png" width="112" height="112" alt="" />
        <img class="hover" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Perspective-Button-Search-icon.png" width="112" height="112" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
Forgot to specify the width, height and position:relative for the image class.
I prepared an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wnw1yuw5/1/

Comment: This is actually closer to what I am trying to do. Just a note, I will have to put all the style elements into the div in html so I can use class tags generically. I'll post a jifddle as soon as I get something close to working.

Comment: So, I've been continuing on this. 
What I've noticed is that I could not get the hover image to appear when I used absolute positioning in the .image class in CSS, except for the last image added in code, essentially the item on top. This is a 2.5D stack on images so they appear from upper left and stack to lower right. If no positioning is used, the images stack vertically as you would expect and the hover function works. I've even tried using a z-index for each of the 10 images. No positioning and things all move back to where I've specifically positioned them, hove limited to the top div.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what kind of display you want but is that what you're looking for ?

```
.productionlines { 
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: all 0.5s;
} 
.productionlines:hover{ 
    opacity: 1;
}
.productionlines .desc{
    opacity: 0;

    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.productionlines:hover .desc{
    opacity: 1;
}

<!-- HTML --> 
<div class="animated_lines">
    <!-- Vertical Blend Button Start -->    
    <div class="productionlines">
        <a href="http://google.ca">
            <img width="300px" src="http://cdx.dexigner.com/article/16326/Dell_Microsoft_PRODUCT_RED_Branded_Products_01_thumb.jpg" />
            <div class="desc">
                <h3>Your title</h3>
                <p>Some text here...</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Vertical Blend Button End -->
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xu8ksvay/

Comment: Yeah!@  I think that will work great.  Looks like I need to read up on the block and cursor tags. -  Thanks!